# generic type binary search tree in java

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I want to implement a generic type binary search tree. The declarations are as follow:

```
public BTNode<T> {}

public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {}

public class BinarySearchTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinaryTree<T> {}
```

Now I have written a class called Entry and want to store the instances of this class in the BinarySearchTree.

```
public class Entry implements Comparable{
private String firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber;

public Entry(String fName, String lName, String address, String phoneNum) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNum;
}

public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

But when I declare `BinarySearchTree<Entry> bst`, there is always an compile error saying:

> "Bound mismatch : The type Entry is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter > of the type
>   BinarySearchTree"

I am still quite new to the generic type in Java. Can anybody help me solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<T>>` this line in your interface should be `<T implements Comparable<T>>`

Comment: no, <T extends Comparable<T>> is correct!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen no it should not: `extends` is used in generics regardless of classes or interfaces. If you want to say T that `extends Foo implements Bar`, then you use `<T extends Foo & Bar>`

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Entry` class needs to implement `Comparable<Entry>` instead of the raw `Comparable`, as the raw `Comparable` doesn't match `Comparable<T>`.

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

Make your Entry class implement `Comparable<Entry>` so that it conforms to the contract of BinaryTree.

The contract says *"all types T that extend (or implement) the type Comparable<T>"*. Of you replace "T" with "Entry", you see that this is required: `Entry extends Comparable<Entry>`